# Change the class on click

Tags: jquery, html, css, class, toggle

I have this HTML code containing a list with four labels, last one is outside the screen. And is supposed to appear only when 2nd or 3rd or 4th label is clicked. But...

```
    <div class="tab-container">
    <ol>
        <input type="radio" id="choice-profile" style="display:none;">
        <li class="prolifeLiClass" id="profileLi">
            <label class="ProfileLabel" onclick="toggle_set1()" for="choice-profile">Profile</label>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" id="choice-privacy" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <label class="PrivacyLabel" for="choice-privacy" onclick="toggle_set2()">Privacy</label>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" id="choice-social" style="display:none;">
        <li>
            <label class="SocialLabel" for="choice-social" onclick="toggle_set3()">Social</label>
        </li>
        <input type="radio" id="choice-misc" style="display:none;">
        <li>
        <label class="MiscLabel" for="choice-misc" onclick="toggle_set4()">Misc</label>
        </li>
    </ol>
    </div>
```

And this css

```
    .tab-container{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:#EEE;
        overflow-x:hidden;
    }
    ol{
        padding:0px;
        margin:0px;
        list-style-type:none;
        width:125%;
        height:33px;
    }
    ol li{
        float:left;
        width:25%;
        text-align:center;
        padding:7px;
        border-left:solid 1px #CCC;
    }
    .profileLiClass{
        margin-left:0%;
    }
    .profileLiClass.clicked1{
        margin-left:0%;
    }
    .profileLiClass.clicked23{
        margin-left:-15%;
    }
    .profileLiClass.clicked4{
        margin-left:-20%;
    }
```

And this jQuery to toggle the class when label is clicked

```
    $("label.PrivacyLabel").click(onPrivacyLabel);
    function onPrivacyLabel()
    {
        $("#profileLi").toggleClass("clicked23");
    }
    $("label.SocialLabel").click(onSocialLabel);
    function onSocialLabel()
    {
        $("#profileLi").toggleClass("clicked23");
    }
    $("label.ProfileLabel").click(onProfileLabel);
    function onProfileLabel()
    {
        $("#profileLi").toggleClass("clicked1");
    }
    $("label.MiscLabel").click(onMiscLabel);
    function onMiscLabel()
    {
        $("#profileLi").toggleClass("clicked4");
    }
```

But this code is not working. Whenever I click the label nothing happens.
I cant seem to know what is wrong with this code.
Can anybody please help?

Comment: Do you define `toggle_set1` (and 2, 3, 4) somewhere?

Comment: Just use variables to toggle boolean values on click. E.g boo Privateer = true; Then inside the social label wrap an if statement around the function and so on...

Comment: @Gothdo Yeah but that has different functions

Comment: Do you have any errors in console? And could you post a fiddle?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Second why are you using inline JavaScript AND jQuery for your event handlers? It's recommend to avoid inline JS whenever possible.